# Calling on a function from a different script, in Unity C# - without referencing the name of the script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im just getting in to Unity and object-orientated programming, with some experience working with JS.

Right away, I run into a problem trying to get two scripts to communicate...
Most solutions reference to another script component by using its name. In my program, connections between scripts have to be able to change dynamically. To do this I'm trying to reference to the script using the inspector.

This is my two scripts:

Script one (simpleSwitchScript):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class simpleSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void testFunction()
    {
        Debug.Log("Working!");
    }
}
```

Script two (receiverScript):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class receiverScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Component sendTo;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Confirm component is assigned
        Debug.Log(sendTo);

        sendTo.testFunction();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Picture of the inspector in Unity:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMBOP.png)

This isn't working, the method "sendTo.testFunction()" is not being called. Im sure the reason is obvious to someone, but I can't figure it out.
Note, I have to reference the script in the inspector.

All the tutorials I find is about connecting two predetermined scripts. In my program, I need the connection between scripts to be dynamic.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile, you should be having errors in the console about this

Comment: Not all `Component` instances will have a `testFunction` method. You need to have the specific type if it is not a function the base class implements.

Comment: Look into `inheritance`, `polymorphism`, and `encapsulation`.

Comment: If you really really want to go that way you could use [`SendMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) ... it is quite a dirty hack around though ... usually you would rather use a proper base class or interface ... note that in contrary to JavaScript, `c#` is a **strictly typed** language!

Comment: `I need the connection between scripts to be dynamic.` you might rather want to go the other way round and instead of actively sending to a specific target rather have an event your other object(s) can listen to ([observer pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)) .. depends a lot on your use case and needs of course you shared no details about

Answer (score 0):

C# is a static-typed language, that means the type of each object is known by compiler to some extent, hence its properties, fields and methods are also known. If you wish to call a function `Foo()` on a component which is determined at runtime, you may implement an interface `IFoo` which provides `void Foo()` method for all such components that could be plugged into, so you'll be able to do things like `var foo = GetComponent<IFoo>();`

In general, to implement some approaches to the modularity that JS has out of the box, in C# you'll need some boilerplate code. We calling it the Architecture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still don't get how to implement this though. Could you share a topic for me to study?

Comment: To begin with I recommend this compact observation of concepts: https://unity.com/how-to/develop-modular-flexible-codebase-state-programming-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what you asked for, i have not found a way to do that. however here is a 2 solutions you can use in the mean time

1. Use find object of type to find the script

   ```
    FindObjectOfType<simpleSwitch>().TestFunction();
   ```

Just put this in your start void of the receiver script and boom!

2. Use

   ```
    sendTo.GetComponent<simpleSwitch>().TestFunction();
   ```

When you use this you need to make sure to reference the object not the script [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBjzm.png)

Sorry I could not be more helpful, but i have not found a way to dynamically change scripts yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Alright, let's get some facts straight. C# is not JS, JS is not C#, it's true that C# is a very distant cousin of Java, so a lot of Java and C# devs can "inter-code", depending on projects, but JavaScript is a different animal.

I can understand you want dynamic calls, and in this case, some might recommend [Reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming), which would work fine, but is overkill here. What I recommend is you read more in-depth about OOP (yes, yes, you say you did, do me a favor and read more, read about C++, Java, C# and even Delphi and when I say "read about..." I mean including other concepts that appear in articles like strong typed, paradigms, garbage collection and so on) and [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

What you want is an [abstract](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_abstract.php) (bet you didn't read about those :p) class that is inherited from. You are actually quite close to the code there.

```
internal abstract class BaseActionSwitch { }
```

(and yes, you'll want an internal class for best practice; if you didn't read up about those, write a comment, trust me, C# is not just a copy-paste language, there are a **LOT** of concepts, paradigms and best-practices to follow)

```
public class simpleSwitch : BaseActionSwitch
{
    public void testFunction()
    {
        Debug.Log("Working!");
    }
}

public class receiverScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BaseActionSwitch sendTo;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Confirm component is assigned
        Debug.Log(sendTo);

        sendTo.testFunction();
    }
}
```

Please understand, the use-case in polymorphism is very specific. For example, it implies you have an abstract base class called Vehicle, and a function `Drive()`. Obviously, you can have a Scooter, a MotorCycle, a Car, the car can be 2WD, 4WD, you can have a bicycle and so on. So `Drive()` would have the same the same [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature), but the code would have different implementations, depending on the child class. If you have more questions about this and want to discuss your actual use-case, write a comment.

On the other hand, you seem to want an event type of a call, so I recommend you look up C# [events](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event) or [UnityEvents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGGmnVIhHvc&themeRefresh=1).

Some might even recommend a "simpler" approach of using static methods. I don't recommend it. If you need help or more info on the above approaches, write a comment and I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in JS so perhaps some paradigms are unknown to me, but as others have said C# is a statically typed language.

The methods/attributes you wish to access must be specified/assigned somewhere. I think what you're looking for is some form of inheritance. This will allow you to interact with different classes that share common/derived methods/attributes.

Every script you make in Unity by default extends from the Monobehaviour class, which in turn is derived from the Component class. In short, the reason you can assign your unrelated script in that field you've created in the inspector is because your script derives from that class. However, the Component class does not contain any method called "TestFunction()", hence why it's not working.

If all you want to do is access different scripts/classes at runtime, then this can be achieved by just using `GetComponent` (Or its derivatives), or something like `FindObjectOfType` (This is quite expensive so don't make a habit of using it), to get a reference to the script you want to interact with and access everything that way.

Using your example, you could do:

```
  public Component sendTo; //Component, GameObject, doesn't matter, 
                          //we're just going to be getting the 
                         //component we specify on whatever
                        //is assigned here

    void Start()
    {
        sendTo.GetComponent<simpleSwitch>().testFunction();
    }
```

However if you wanted to have different scripts that share common members, then you could either:

- Create a base class that implements these functions, then create multiple derived classes.
- Use an interface, which allows you to implement methods in said interface in other classes.

Here's an example of the first option, using base/derived classes:

```
public class baseSwitch: MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void testFunction()
    {
       /*A virtual function let's us override whatever's in
         the base class if we want to. If you don't want
         any functionality in the base class, then 
         you should make it an abstract class.*/
    }
}
```

```
public class derivedSwitch: baseSwitch
{
    public override void testFunction() 
    {
       //We can write different code here
       Debug.Log("This is the derived switch class!");
    }
}
```

Then, to access this:

```
public class receiverScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public baseSwitch sendTo;

    void Start()
    {
        sendTo.testFunction();
        //This will run whatever is in the override method of the 
        //assigned derived class, or if there is no override,
        //whatever code is in the base method.
    }
}
```

You could also have a derived class that implements new methods that are not in its base class, and then access those by casting down:

```
public class derivedSwitch: baseSwitch
{
    public override void testFunction() 
    {
       //We can write different code here
       Debug.Log("This is the derived switch class!");
    }

    public void functionNotInBaseClass()
    {
       Debug.Log("This is not in baseSwitch.cs!");
    }

}
public class receiverScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public baseSwitch sendTo;

    void Start()
    {
        (sendTo as derivedSwitch).functionNotInBaseClass();
    }
}
```

The other option, interfaces, can offer some more flexibility as classes which implement them can derive from whatever class we like:

```
public interface TestInterface
{
    //Interfaces, like abstract classes, only allow for methods to be defined.
    void testFunction();
}
```

Then we can implement this in a class:

```
public class baseSwitch: MonoBehaviour, TestInterface
{
    public void testFunction() //We must implement this function
    {
       Debug.Log("Implemented from TestInterface");
    }
}
```

We can then access this as follows:

```
public class receiverScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TestInterface sendTo;

    void Start()
    {
        sendTo.testFunction();
    }
}
```

If you have any more questions about how to implement this, perhaps ones specifically related to your use case, leave a comment and I'll be happy to help :)

If you have questions about how to access various scripts in Unity then I will point you to [this answer I wrote recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76879732/20232776).